# can't update field in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i update my `revisor_id` from my `Petition` model, i want to automatically update my `revisor_id` from my `Post` model.

So, in my `petitions_controller.rb` i added this line within the `update` method:

```
@petition.post.revisor_id = @petition.revisor_id
```

With the debugger i can see that after the line is executed, both are set correctly. But it seems like it's not saved in the database or something, because when i request to show all the posts with revisor_id set to 1, it doesnt show anything.

I believe it has something to do with strong parameters since i just chaged to rails 4, but not sure.

Any idea?

```
#petitions_controller.rb
...
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @petition.update(petition_params)
        @petition.post.revisor_id = @petition.revisor_id
        format.html { redirect_to @petition, notice: 'Petition was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @petition }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @petition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_petition
      @petition = Petition.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def petition_params
      params.require(:petition).permit(:user_id, :category_id, :revisor_id, :status, :post_id)
    end
```

Comment: Can you post your server log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling save.

```
@petition.post.update_attibute(:revisor_id, @petition.revisor_id)
```

Or

```
@petition.post.revisor_id = @petition.revisor_id
@petition.post.save
```

But it looks like you could redesign your database and you has_one through so you wouldn't need to do that.